# Unable to launch the dialog modal in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, dialog, modal-dialog

I have used the following code in my workspace project as a part of a large application and ir worked fine. I am trying to isolate the page into a stand alone and cannot seem to get the dialog pop up. Shown below is the code, can someone please comment on why it won't pop up the modal dialog ? Thanks in advance and I appreciate your time.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="firstCtrl">

    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                        data-toggle="modal" data- 
target="#selectOptionTestDialog">Options</button>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="selectOptionTestDialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"   
aria-labelledby="myCaseLabel"
        aria-hidden="true" >
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form name="formShowOptions" role="form">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <p>Execution Steps</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        Select Execution Step : 
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I believe that the modal is part of angular-ui-bootstrap, or boostrap itself, but I don´t see any of these scripts loaded on the page.

Comment: It appears that you're using the regular Bootstrap modal. If you're using AngularJS, I recommend you take a look at the $modal service available in UI.Bootstrap. http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include JQuery and Bootstrap js files

```
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```